# Degrees rotation based on frequency offset?

Tags: doppler

What is the relationship to calculate degrees of rotation in the constellation given a baud rate and frequency offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frequency is the derivative of phase over time; phase hence frequency's integral over time. And that's all the knowledge you need, since baudrate gives you the time between consecutive symbols.

Comment: to measure the phase rotation caused by a given frequency offset across a frame/burst/slot of data, is it fair to say it's not a function of the baudrate but rather the duration of that frame/burst/slot ? The delta t would be the burst duration in that case?

Comment: since the baudrate would define the length of a burst, I don't think that is an overly sensible statement, no.

Comment: I believe we are in agreement. Plenty of commercial specs define bursts in terms of duration in seconds.